# whty is my hashmap adding duplicate details

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have this block of code.

I need to return  hashmap that has the gender as key,and another hashmaap  value the second hash map has yearofbirth as key and arraylist of all people with that saame yearofbear in it .

wrote this code but when i print it prints duplicates of the same customer and employees

```java
public HashMap<Gender, HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Person>>> personsByGenderAndYearOfBirth() {
    ArrayList<Person> Males=new ArrayList<Person>();
    ArrayList<Person> Females=new ArrayList<Person>();
    HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Person>> AccBirthDateMale=new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Person>> AccBirthDateFemale=new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Gender, HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Person>>> AccGender=new HashMap<>();
    for(HashMap.Entry<String, Customer> entry : allCustomers.entrySet())
    {
        {
            switch(entry.getValue().getGender())
            {
            case M:
                Males.add(entry.getValue());
                AccBirthDateMale.put(entry.getValue().getYearOfBirth(),Males);
                break;
            case F:

                Females.add(entry.getValue());
                AccBirthDateFemale.put(entry.getValue().getYearOfBirth(),Females);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    AccGender.put(Gender.F, AccBirthDateFemale);
    AccGender.put(Gender.M, AccBirthDateMale);
    for(HashMap.Entry<String, Employee> entry : allEmployees.entrySet())
    {
        switch(entry.getValue().getGender())
        {
            case M:
                Males.add(entry.getValue());
                AccBirthDateMale.put(entry.getValue().getYearOfBirth(),Males);
                break;
            case F:
                Females.add(entry.getValue());
                AccBirthDateFemale.put(entry.getValue().getYearOfBirth(),Females);
                break;
        }
    }
    AccGender.put(Gender.F, AccBirthDateFemale);
    AccGender.put(Gender.M, AccBirthDateMale);
    System.out.println(AccBirthDateMale.toString());
    System.out.println(AccGender.toString());
    return AccGender;
}
```

Comment: Please share a reproductible code. [edit] and add classes and a main so we can try it. Also share the output, that's always better than words

Comment: I'd also *strongly* recommend that you start following Java naming conventions - at the moment, the convention violations are really, really distracting, at least to me. (I'd focus on providing a [mcve] - both complete *and* minimal are important. I suspect your complete example doesn't need to be any longer than the incomplete example you've provided so far...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Problem

The issue is that you add a person to its gender list, no matter the year, then use this list of the person's year, so every year ends up pointing to the same and unique genderlist

```
Males.add(entry.getValue());
AccBirthDateMale.put(entry.getValue().getYearOfBirth(), Males);
```

---

##### Fix

You add the outer mapping directly at initialisation of the resulting map

Iterate directly over the values of the map, then you gendered map per year, and add the mapping if it's missing, add the person to its year, and finally year

```
Map<Gender, Map<Integer, List<Person>>> result = Map.of(Gender.M, accBirthDateMale, Gender.F, accBirthDateFemale);

for (Person person : allCustomers.values()) {
    switch (person.getGender()) {
        case M:
            if(!accBirthDateMale.containsKey(person.getYearOfBirth())){
                accBirthDateMale.put(person.getYearOfBirth(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            accBirthDateMale.get(person.getYearOfBirth()).add(person);
            break;
        case F:
            if(!accBirthDateFemale.containsKey(person.getYearOfBirth())){
                accBirthDateFemale.put(person.getYearOfBirth(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            accBirthDateFemale.get(person.getYearOfBirth()).add(person);
            break;
    }
}
result.put(Gender.M, accBirthDateMale);
result.put(Gender.F, accBirthDateFemale);
```

---

##### Improve

The previous code is quite verbose, and map offers nice methods to handle the missing-key case (`computeIfAbsent`)

```
public static Map<Gender, Map<Integer, List<Person>>> personsByGenderAndYearOfBirth() {
    Map<Gender, Map<Integer, List<Person>>> result = Map.of(Gender.M, new HashMap<>(), Gender.F, new HashMap<>());
    for(Collection<? extends Person> people : List.of(allCustomers.values(), allEmployees.values())){
        for (Person person : people) {
            result.get(person.getGender()).computeIfAbsent(person.getYearOfBirth(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(person);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

##### Improve bis

Using `Streams`

```
public static Map<Gender, Map<Integer, List<Person>>> personsByGenderAndYearOfBirthBis() {
    return Stream.of(allCustomers.values(), allEmployees.values())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender, Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getYearOfBirth, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Comment: thanks so much u solved it . i'm currently in uni and not supposed to use methods that i haven't learned . and i'm also pretty new to here sorry if my question was a bit stupid.i couldn't add my full project because its about a 1000 lines . thanks

Comment: @hsnsaed you’re welcome. I didn’t meant your whole code, but the minimal amount required to run the method and test it